# Can the UK access my history in the Schengen Visa Information System?

Tags: visas, uk, france

United Kingdom is able to know that France was refused to give me a visa or no?

I have a prior refusal from France (assume Schengen short-stay).  I want to know if this event is stored in the Schengen Visa Information System (VIS), and if so do the UK authorities have access to the VIS in a way that my history can be queried directly.

Comment: Would another way of phrasing your question be, "The UK immigration authorities are asking if I have ever been refused entry to another country.  I have.  Am I likely to get away with lying?"

Comment: UK has one of the stringent visa regimes existing anywhere and follows the  regulations to the word. Lie and forget about entering UK maybe ever. Tell the truth and explain the circumstances of refusal.

Comment: This is a duplicate - although I can't find the original right now.

Comment: @CMaster they all dissolve into a blur after a while. Our stuff, however, is mostly concerned with the polar opposite of this question.  Since the sharing arrangement is symmetric it could be considered a 'virtual duplicate'. You can write an answer on that basis with comfort that the question will not be closed as a duplicate, but act quick because it's likely to be closed on something else like 'unclear' or 'opinion-based'.

Answer (score 2):

The UK (along with Ireland) does not participate in the Visa Information System:

"As a Schengen instrument, this regulation applies to EU countries with the exception of the United Kingdom and Ireland. Denmark has decided to implement the regulation which also applies to Iceland, Norway and Switzerland."

Thus it should not have any access to data held in the VIS.

However, should you inform the UK authorities you have been refused a visa in France, no doubt they will ask the French authorities for any information they hold on you.

N.B. There is also the Schengen Information System - a different database - to which the UK does have access. However, unless you have been banned from entering the Schengen area, your data should not be stored within it (as far as I understand).

Comment: +1, do you have an authoritative source explaining that the UK is not an end-user of the Schengen VIS? Some of the answers in our archives indicate that the UK does participate in maintaining the VIS, despite that they are not a signatory to Schengen. Can you provide some substance? Thanks.